# How to get the total amount of the orders? (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[order history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk1Zp.png)

I would like to get the total amounts per order, however, I cannot get the value of the quantity in an array

[Quantity in an array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dnNi.png)

I would like to know how to get the value of the quantity in the array so that I can multiply it by to order amount? Or is there another way to get the total amount of the orders?

Comment: you have 2 items under products object, so you will pick first always ? like products[0].quantity

Comment: *"I cannot get the value of the quantity in an array"* - Why can't you?  What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what you want to do with the quantity, nor how you will get the price of the product, but I try to give some help anyway.

Let's say you have an orders array, if you just need to extract all the quantities you can just do like this:

```js
orders.forEach(order => {
  const products = order.products;
  products.forEach(product => {
    const quantity = product.quantity;
    console.log(quantity);
  });
});
```

If you had a function that can give you the price of the single item, for example something like `getProductValue()` you can compute the total like this:

```js
orders.forEach(order => {
  const products = order.products;
  products.forEach(product => {
    const quantity = product.quantity;
    const value = getProductValue(product.id);
    const total = quantity * value;
    console.log(total);
  });
});
```

You can also create an array with all the amounts like this:

```js
const allAmounts = orders.reduce((valuesList, order) => {
  const products = order.products;
  const values = products.map(product => {
    const quantity = product.quantity;
    const value = getProductValue(product.id);
    const total = quantity * value;
    return total;
  });
  valuesList = valuesList.concat(values);
  return valuesList;
}, []);
```

Or you can even sum all the values like this:

```
const totalSum = orders.reduce((totalOrderValue, order) => {
  const products = order.products;
  const productSum = products.reduce((totalProductValue, product) => {
    const quantity = product.quantity;
    const value = getProductValue(product.id);
    const total = quantity * value;
    return totalProductValue += total;
  }, 0);
  totalOrderValue = totalOrderValue + productSum;
  return totalOrderValue;
}, 0);
```

Here is a complete snippet with a fake orders array and a fake `getProductValue` function and the totalSum computation:

```js
const orders = [
  {
    _id: 'xxx',
    products: [
      {
        title: 'ptitle',
        id: 'dfsdsge',
        quantity: 4,
      },
      {
        title: 'ptitle',
        id: 'sdfrer',
        quantity: 2,
      }
    ]
  }, 
  {
    _id: 'dddd',
    products: [
      {
        title: 'ptitle',
        id: 'dfsdsge',
        quantity: 2,
      },
      {
        title: 'ptitle',
        id: 'sdfrer',
        quantity: 23,
      }
    ]
  }, 
  {
    _id: 'eee',
    products: [
      {
        title: 'ptitle',
        id: 'dfsdsge',
        quantity: 7,
      },
      {
        title: 'ptitle',
        id: 'sdfrer',
        quantity: 2,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 'zzzz',
    products: [
      {
        title: 'ptitle',
        id: 'dfsdsge',
        quantity: 2,
      },
      {
        title: 'ptitle',
        id: 'sdfrer',
        quantity: 1,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 'hhh',
    products: [
      {
        title: 'ptitle',
        id: 'dfsdsge',
        quantity: 1,
      },
      {
        title: 'ptitle',
        id: 'sdfrer',
        quantity: 1,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 'wedsd',
    products: [
      {
        title: 'ptitle',
        id: 'dfsdsge',
        quantity: 78,
      },
      {
        title: 'ptitle',
        id: 'sdfrer',
        quantity: 8,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 'wedsd',
    products: [
      {
        title: 'ptitle',
        id: 'dfsdsge',
        quantity: 6,
      },
      {
        title: 'ptitle',
        id: 'sdfrer',
        quantity: 1,
      }
    ]
  }
];

const getProductValue = id => {
  return 5;
}

const totalSum = orders.reduce((totalOrderValue, order) => {
  const products = order.products;
  const productSum = products.reduce((totalProductValue, product) => {
    const quantity = product.quantity;
    const value = getProductValue(product.id);
    const total = quantity * value;
      return totalProductValue += total;
  }, 0);
  totalOrderValue = totalOrderValue + productSum;
  return totalOrderValue;
}, 0);

console.log(totalSum);
```

Comment: Hi sir, I really appreciate your response. Now my problem here is that I tried to multiply the quantity amount by my order amount, (which is the amount for the single product) but I am getting a result that shows like this:

Comment: `OrderHistory.jsx:95 Total Amount of quantity & amount 60000
OrderHistory.jsx:95 Total Amount of quantity & amount 5000
OrderHistory.jsx:95 Total Amount of quantity & amount 7200
2OrderHistory.jsx:95 Total Amount of quantity & amount 60000
OrderHistory.jsx:95 Total Amount of quantity & amount 5000
OrderHistory.jsx:95 Total Amount of quantity & amount 7200
2OrderHistory.jsx:95 Total Amount of quantity & amount 60000
OrderHistory.jsx:95 Total Amount of quantity & amount 5000
OrderHistory.jsx:95 Total Amount of quantity & amount 7200

Comment: {orders.forEach((order) => {
              const products = order.products;
              products.forEach((product) => {
                const quantity = product.quantity;
                const orderAmount = order.amount;
                const total = quantity * orderAmount;

                console.log("Total Amount of quantity & amount", total);
              });
            })}

Comment: I’m not sure that you should multiply the quantity of every item by the amount of the order: order.amount seems to be already the total. Anyway if what you’re doing is correct, you should declare a variable before this code (like let totalAmount = 0;) and add the total to that variable just before the console.log, like totalAmount = totalAmount + total;. At the end of the loop you should have the total in the totalAmount variable. You can print it or do what you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines:

```
let sumOfQuantity = 0;
ORDERS[3].products.forEach(x => {
    sumOfQuantity += x.quantity;
})
console.log("Total: " + (ORDERS[3].amount * sumOfQuantity))
```

If you need to do this for every order just do ORDERS.forEach in the same mannor